# Linear Transformation: Notation confusion

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm having a hard time understanding the meaning of this notation:

Let $V $ be a (possibly infinite-dimensional) vector space over a field $\mathbb F.$ Let $S: V →  \mathbb F$ and let $T : V → \mathbb F$ be linear transformations.

How can we have a map from $V$ to $\mathbb F$? What do the elements of $\mathbb F$ look like? Are they just scalars?
Does this notation just mean that every vector in $V$ is mapped to a scalar in $\mathbb F$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a linear map can map to a space of higher or lower dimension than the source vector space. In this case the map is to a space of dimension$~1$, which is probably less the that of the source space.

Examples: if $V$ is a space of polynomials in $X$ and $a\in F$ is some fixed value, then the map $S$ evaluation the polynomial after setting $X=a$ is a linear map $V\to F$. Another example, if $F$ is $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, and $W$ is the space of convergent sequences of elements of $F$, then the map $T$ assigning its limit to a sequence is a linear map $W\to F$. Also using any basis, the map assigning to $v$ the coordinate of $v$, with respect to this basis, of a particular basis vector, is always a linear map. In the infinite dimensional case there may be  linear maps that are not obtained as (finite!) linear combinations of such coordinate functions; the polynomial evaluation in $a\neq0$ is an example (with the basis of the monomials).